# Servicestack.Text ConvertTo<> tomap properties with different names or any other solution for this?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, servicestack, servicestack-text

Consider I have these classes in my Api model, because other actions may need customerData with different attributes I hide base properties like this:

```
public class CustomerData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string PublicKey { get; set; }
}
```

and this class:

```
     public class AddCustomerInput:CustomerData
        {
            [Required]
            public new string Name { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public new string PublicKey { get; set; }
       }
```

these two models are in Api level and I have another model in domain level:

```
   public class ExternalCustomerData
        {              
            public new string CustomerName{ get; set; }               
            public new string PublicKey { get; set; }
        }
```

as you can see name here is customerName, also these models are big with different names in api and domain model names but I shortened the models,

also I have this extension method to convert types:

```
    public static ExternalCustomerData ToExternalCustomerData(this CustomerData customerData)
    {
        //All properties with same property names convert correctly
        var externalCustomerData =customerData.ConvertTo<ExternalCustomerData>();
        //but the result of customerData.Name is null
        externalCustomerData .CustomerName= customerData.Name ;
        return externalCustomerData ;
    }
```

when I use this extension method for AddCustomerInput:

```
addCustomerInputObject.ToExternalCustomerData();
```

I see All properties with same property names convert correctly but this line:

```
externalCustomerData .CustomerName= customerData.Name
```

is null.
I was wondering what is the reason servicestack cast this parent object to child correcly, how can I achieve change in name? 
I want to know is it possible to get the result with servicestack.text convertTo? If not is there any good solution for doing this?

*I know i can have

```
 public static ExternalCustomerData ToExternalCustomerData(this AddCustomerInput customerData)
        {
        }
```

and it works fine but I have many  apiInput models which all of them inherit from CustomerData and I should have many extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

No [ServiceStack's Auto Mapping](http://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping) doesn't support mapping properties with different names, the recommendation is to [use Extension Methods](http://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping#advanced-mapping-using-custom-extension-methods) to handle any additional customization's needed.